# Google Chrome JavaScript Debugger keybindings?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome's JavaScript debugger to work on my code, but I am finding it very inconvenient to constantly move my mouse over to the Go, Step Over and Step In buttons. I find it much easier to hit a function key, like I would in Visual Studio or most graphical debuggers really, do perform those actions.

I can not find any documentation to suggest that such keybindings are available, but I can scarcely believe that such crucial functionality would be over-looked by the Chromium team.

Can anyone offer any help or insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you press F1 while in the debugger, you can see a list of shortcuts.

Examples:
- `F8 or <Ctrl>+/`  : Continue
- `F10 or <Ctrl>+'` : Step over
- `F11 or <Ctrl>+;` : Step into
- `<Shift>+F11 or <Ctrl>+<Shift>+;` : Step out
- `<Ctrl>+G`        : Go to Line

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know why, but on my Mac Book Pro, these shortcuts only work when I use the Command Key instead of Control

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Javascript debugger. Is that the tool you are looking for? Very handy :)

ohh, and for step functions, <kbd>F10</kbd> for step over, <kbd>F11</kbd> is step into. Same as the VS keys, except <kbd>F5</kbd> refreshes the page.

Comment: This answer is also correct, and how silly do I feel for not having tried the Visual Studio key bindings when that was the example that I used. I have been doing so much Python programming in Wing IDE lately that I must have tried its slightly different keys.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector

Comment: Actually, no it isn't what I am looking for, but thanks. Chrome has excellent debugging facilities rolled-in, but my question was about the key to hit to trigger the Step In action in the debugger.

Comment: Google Chrome and Safari share the same webkit development tools which includes JavaScript debugging . Documentation was not overlooked by Chromium team, it's just posted on webkit website. The link that I have provided its for the "missing docs" and it has all the key bindings you may need and other useful info. I also use Chrome and I keep this this website pinned for quick reference.

Comment: Most fabulous. I was looking for a replacement for F11 on a Macbook Pro. That link had it. Command ;